# Generic Method Definition contains <T extends Class> in-spite of return type is already Defined?

Tags: java, generics

Can any body explain why `<T extends Job>`   Typed-safe generics  is used here ??

This code was written by one of my project team member who is no more part of the team. This looks like a strange `Code` for me. I just want to rewrite this and use it in another Code. Without deep Understanding i won't be able to change this.

```
    private <T extends Job> void addNewTask (Class<T> prm_objClassToSchedule, String prm_sJobName, String prm_sTriggerName, String prm_sCronExpression) throws ParseException, SchedulerException {
            CronTrigger v_objTrigger;
            JobDetail v_objJob;
            Scheduler v_objScheduler;
}
```

Comment: The method is private, so you can show us the callers with the object parameters. Maybe we can know more

Comment: How `prm_objClassToSchedule` is used in `addNewTask` ?

Comment: how the method `addNewTask` is called.
which object is passed as `prm_objClassToSchedule`

Comment: @adranale I am just here to know why function is written like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As told in other answers `T` should extend `Job`, so the method could be clearly written like this:

```
private <T extends Job> void addNewTask (Class<T extends Job> prm_objClassToSchedule, String prm_sJobName, String prm_sTriggerName, String prm_sCronExpression) throws ParseException, SchedulerException {
            CronTrigger v_objTrigger;
            JobDetail v_objJob;
            Scheduler v_objScheduler;
```

The java compiler needs at least one mention to the exact type of the same generic type `T` to be able to compile it, no matter if this mention is in the parameter or in the return type. All the other mentions of `T` will be interpreted as the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Without any context for which this method is used. I would say that the first parameter is expecting a Class type that extends from the Job class.

Comment: yes i know that. Please explain deeply. by seeing this i can predict it. but why ? is it neccessary to do so?

Comment: Without further knowledge of your code, I couldn't say why exactly. I can say that it would allow flexibility in what your "prm_objClassToSchedule" can and that the method also depends on it being a Job.

Answer (score 1):

It is stating that the first parameter is a `Class<T>` wheref `T extends Job`.

```
class Job {

    public void go() {

    }
}

class X extends Job {
}

private <T extends Job> void addNewTask(Class<T> c) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    T t = c.newInstance();
    t.go();
}

public void test() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Object o = new Object();
    Job j = new Job();
    X x = new X();
    // Not allowed because `o` is not a `Job`
    //addNewTask(o.getClass());
    // Both good.
    addNewTask(j.getClass());
    addNewTask(x.getClass());
}
```

Comment: I know how to use this method. Only what i want to ask that is it necessary to do so? then why ? any deep reason . you have explained how to use this method not why ??

Comment: @VikrantKashyap - I've adjusted the code - perehaps that explains it better.